# Quickest way to delete redundant lines in bash, or delete last line if string is #

Tags: text-processing

Looking for an elegant way, when at the end of a `bash` script to cleanup the resulting file if:

1. the first character of the line below the line to be deleted is `#` **or**
2. `#` is the first character of the last line in the file.

File could look like this (line numbers of reference are in `[]` but are **not** in the file itself):

```
[1] # foo
[2] bar1
[3] bar2
[4] bar3
[5] # foob
[6] #ar
[7] ar1
[8] ar2
[9] ar3
[10] #
```

In the above example I'd like to delete lines 5 and 10.  I do not want any line starting with `#` to be followed by a line starting with `#` and I do not want the last line of the file to start with `#`.

EDIT: Expected output:

```
[1] # foo
[2] bar1
[3] bar2
[4] bar3
[5] #ar
[6] ar1
[7] ar2
[8] ar3
```

Teaching myself `bash` as I go and am *super* confused by `sed` and `awk` syntax, but I suspect they are the answer here.

Comment: Can you please add expected output ?

Comment: Why isn't line `[4]` deleted? the first character of the line below it is also `#`

Comment: you say that [5] is to be deleted ... the only way to do that is to delete [4] and then rule #1 deletes [5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you want is

```
sed -e '${/^#/d}' -e '$!N;/^#.*\n#/D' -e 'P;D' file
```

- `${/^#/d}` address the last line `$`; if it matches `^#` then delete it
- `$!N` ... `P;D` maintain a rolling two-line buffer
- `/^#.*\n#/D` if there is a `#` both at the start of the pattern and after the newline, delete up to the newline and begin a new cycle

Answer (score 2):

Your requirements can be coded in `sed` as shown.

```
sed -e '
  /^#/!b
  $d;N
  /\n#/D
' file
```

- Any non interesting line is taken to stdout, meaning printed: `/^#/!b`
- interesting line is one  that begins with a `#`
- last line which happens to be interesting is deleted: `$d`
- Please note that a non interesting line CANNOT come to 2nd sed code line.
- in case the interesting line is not the last line of the file, we append the next line to it: `N`
- if the next line is interesting as well, remove the previous interesting line AND go to the top of the sed script using the existing pattern space:  `/\n#/D`

You should refer to the sed manual for details on the various sed commands used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` multi-line techniques

```
sed -E 'N;s/(^#.*)(#.*)/\2/;${s/(.*)(#.*)/\1/}' file
```

`N` command appends a `newline` and the next line to the pattern space.

for lines with pattern `^#.*#.*` removes the first line.

`${}` for last line checks if the pattern `.*#.*` matches, removes the last part.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^#/{:a;h;n;//b a;H;g;};p' file
```

Option `-n` disables automatic printing, lines will be printed via `p` action. `/^#/{ ... }` – on lines beginning with `#`, perform a group of actions. `:a` ... `b a` sets up a loop, in that loop:

- `h` replaces the hold space with the pattern space (i.e. saves the current line to a buffer).
- `n` reads the next line of input into the pattern space (or quits there is no more input).
- `//b a` – `b`ranch to `:a` if pattern space matches `/^#/`. In `sed`, an empty regular expression is shorthand for `apply the last used regex`.

Once loop is finished: `H;g` – append current pattern space to the hold space and replace pattern space with hold space. `p` at the end prints the result from the loop, and every other non-`#` line.

Result: only the last of any group of `#` lines is printed, and no `#` lines before the end.

```
# foo
bar1
bar2
bar3
#ar
ar1
ar2
ar3
```